# How to apply style to a view that is part of a custom view

Tags: android, android-view

I want to create a custom view, which is basically just a `LinearLayout`, which contains multiple `ImageView`s. Layout itself is very simple, so no `xml` is needed as everything is added inside the `init` block.

The thing is, that style, that I am trying to apply to `ImageView`s is ignored. At first, I thought that the problem is, that I'm applying it through custom attribute of `Icons` view, **but the same happens if I apply it directly through `ImageView`'s constructor**.

I'm providing entire code anyway, in case anyone finds anything else I'm doing wrong although `getResourceId(R.styleable.Icons_iconsStyle, 0)` returns value different than 0.

In `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Icons">
    <item name="android:layout_width">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
</style>
```

In `attrs.xml`:

```
<declare-styleable name="Icons">
    <attr name="iconsStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

`Icons.kt`:

```
class Icons @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val someIcon: ImageView

    init {
        @StyleRes
        val iconsStyle: Int

        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Icons, 0, 0).apply {
            iconsStyle = getResourceId(R.styleable.Icons_iconsStyle, 0)

            recycle()
        }

        someIcon = ImageView(context, null, iconsStyle)
            .apply { 
                setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon) 
            }
            .also {
                addView(it)
            }
    }
}
```

In `fragment_layout.xml`:

```
<com.example.Icons
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:iconsStyle="@style/AppTheme.Icons" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't managed to figure this out, so I took a more direct approach: instead of using style for `ImageView`s, I set size and margin directly from `dimens`.

Here's the end result:

```
class Icons @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    private val someIcon: ImageView

    init {

        val iconSize = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_size)
        val margin = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.icon_margin)

        someIcon = ImageView(context, null)
            .apply { 
                setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_icon)
                layoutParams = LayoutParams(iconSize, iconSize).apply {
                    setMargins(margin)
                }
            }
            .also {
                addView(it)
            }
    }
}
```